# On the directional derivative of $\frac{x^2}{y}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ the function defined by:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{y} & \text{if} \ \ y\neq0\\
0 & \text{if} \ \ y=0
\end{cases}
$$
1)Calculate the directional derivative $f_a(0,0)$ in the direction  $a=(h,k)$ of $f$.

2) Study the continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$

My Solution is:

1) We have:

$$f_a(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f((0,0)+t(h,k))-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{t^2h^2}{tk}-f(0,0)}{t}$$

Next, we must evaluate $f(0,0)$: Since $f(x,0)=0$ then $f(0,0)=0$. hence 
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{t^2h^2}{tk}-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{t^2h^2}{tk}}{t}=\frac{h^2}{k}.$$

2) $f$ is not continuous at (0,0) because: if we take $(x,y)=(x,x^3)$ the limit is $+\infty$ and for $(x,y)=(x,x^2)$ we obtain the limit equal to 1.

My question: Does my answer is correct or no? Thank you

Comment: For 1: what happens if $k=0$?

Comment: I think we must take  $(h,k)\neq(0,0)$?

Comment: Sure, but what happens if $a = (h, 0)$ with $h\neq 0$?

Comment: Problem, no limit.

Comment: Why? Compute $f(th, 0)$ using the definition of $f$.

Comment: We obtain that $f(th,0)=0$ and then we deduce??

Answer (score 1):

What if $a = (h,0)$?

The directional derivative:

$$
D_a f(0,0) = lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f((0,0) + t(h,0))-f(0,0)}{t} = 0
$$

by definition of your function.

Comment: What about the continuity of $f$?

Comment: your proof is OK.